# Storing multiple images into firebase and getting urls

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have 100 images that I want to store in firebase storage, but I also need to extract the urls from them. Is there an automatic way of doing it?

If not is there a better service provider that allows uploading a lot of images and extracting the url all automatically??

Comment: Firebase Storage has an API that you can use to upload the images and then get the download URL for each in turn. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend using Firebase Storage and the Firebase Realtime Database together to accomplish this. Some code to show how these pieces interact is below (Swift):

Shared:

```
// Firebase services
var database: FIRDatabase!
var storage: FIRStorage!
...
// Initialize Database, Auth, Storage
database = FIRDatabase.database()
storage = FIRStorage.storage()
```

Upload:

```
let fileData = NSData() // get data...
let storageRef = storage.reference().child("myFiles/myFile")
storageRef.putData(fileData).observeStatus(.Success) { (snapshot) in
  // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get it's download URL
  // This "extracts" the URL, which you can then save to the RT DB
  let downloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
  // Write the download URL to the Realtime Database
  let dbRef = database.reference().child("myFiles/myFile")
  dbRef.setValue(downloadURL)
}
```

Download:

```
let dbRef = database.reference().child("myFiles")
dbRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
  // Get download URL from snapshot
  let downloadURL = snapshot.value() as! String
  // Create a storage reference from the URL
  let storageRef = storage.referenceFromURL(downloadURL)
  // Download the data, assuming a max size of 1MB (you can change this as necessary)
  storageRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
    // Do something with downloaded data...
  })
})
```

For more information, see [Zero to App: Develop with Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE), and it's [associated source code](https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/cc45567cd95ba2a62017cb21e891effd), for a practical example of how to do this.